# Get only folder names using glob.glob * pattern

Tags: python, glob

I am using below line of code to recursively find the folders which has a particular sub-file name endswith `.log`.

```
glob.iglob(f"{ROOT}/**/*.log", recursive = True)
```

Now, this code gives me an iterator which has complete path. But I want to return only the folder names, not whole path.

If this is how my directory looks like:

```
<ROOT>/
├── a/
│   ├── a.log
├── b/
│   └── b.log
├── c/
│   ├── c.log
│   └── cd/
│      └── cd.log
```

I want only the folder names in list like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'c/cd']
```

Is there a way to get only folder names?

Comment: I don't know of a way to get `glob` to only return the folders, but it's trivial to strip the folder from the full filename.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I also got stuck. Post probably I'll have to find some other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `os.path.dirname()` to get the directory name from the filenames.

This is using a set comprehension to avoid duplicates.

```
dirs_where_there_are_logs = {
  os.path.dirname(pth)
  for pth
  in glob.iglob(f"{ROOT}/**/*.log", recursive=True)
}
```

Following the discussion in the comments, if you want dirnames relative to `ROOT`,

```
dirs_where_there_are_logs = {
  os.path.relpath(os.path.dirname(pth), ROOT)
  for pth
  in glob.iglob(f"{ROOT}/**/*.log", recursive=True)
}
```

Comment: If you can rely on `glob` to return all the files in a single directory in sequence, it's not necessary to use a `set` to eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: @MarkRansom If a single directory contains multiple log files, you'd otherwise get multiple instances of the same directory.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my statement.  What I mean is that there's a simpler way than a `set` to eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: But this code is giving me whole path rather than only the folder names.

Comment: If you only then want the last folder name, `os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(...))`.

Comment: Or, you may also want to get rid of the root, so `os.path.relpath(pth, ROOT)`?

Comment: Yes, I think `os.path.relpath` will work, but I think I'll have to use it with `os.path.dirname` to ignore the `.log` file in the output.

Comment: @TonyMontana Great, augmented the answer to reflect that.

Comment: You may want to throw a `if os.path.isfile(pth)` in there in case there is a directory that matches the pattern. Maybe `a/i_am_a_directory.log/a.log`.

Answer (score 1):

The `path` library has tools to help with this:

```
import path

dirs = map(lambda p: path.Path(p).dirname(),
           glob.iglob((f"{ROOT}/**/*.log", recursive=True))

# dirs will contain duplicates for each file found in the same directory
dirs = set(dirs)
```

Answer (score 0):

using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

```
from pathlib import Path
ROOT = f"your_root_dir"
p = Path(f'{ROOT}').glob('**/*.log')
files = [x for x in p if x.is_file()]
all_folders = []
for f in files:
    all_folders.append(f.parent)
    print(f.parent) # it gives full folder path, d.parent.stem if you only want the folder names
```